# Why does movieClip.getBounds() return null?

Tags: javascript, haxe, createjs, flash-cc

In flash cc, I call this method at a movieClip time line:

```
Widget.InsertSelection(this);
```

the movieClip is placed at stage,

`Widget` is an exposed class at haxe js project, so `InsertSelection` will be called with argument of movieClip passed

in haxe `InsertSelection` function:

```
public static function InsertSelection(aSelectionHolder:MovieClip)
{
  trace (aSelectionHolder.getBounds());
}
```

but, I get `null` in chrome console, why is that? how to get x, width of that movie clip?

Comment: This is tagged CreateJS/JavaScript, but you are posting ActionScript. What is this demo using? For CC export to CreateJS, you can access the nominalBounds on any displayObject. Check out the generated JavaScript to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that the movieclip passed has no graphics drawn or Bitmap with bitmapData set, make sure it has something drawn on it and test the method again.

Comment: I tried to put an image, but it didn't work until I set it as cache as bitmap, but the width and height was wrong ..